# How do I stop my Canon Speedlite (430exii) from going to sleep? (auto power off)

Tags: canon, flash, hotshoe-flash, presets

I want to use my Speedlite flash as my main flash off-camera and fire it remotely (with cactus V2 triggers) but I find it really annoying when the camera just goes to sleep and I have to walk over and wake it up again.

Is there any way to disable this power save feature?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "Auto power off" feature can be toggled as one of the unit's "custom features". You need to set feature number 1 to have the value "1".

**To set the custom features:**

1. **Press the "C.Fn" button for 2 sec. or more so that "C.Fn" is displayed on screen.**
2. **Select the Custom Function No.**

   - Press the + button to select the Custom Function number ("01").
3. **Change the setting.**

   - Press the "sel" button.
   - The setting number will blink.
   - Press the + button to set the desired number ("1"), then press the "sel" button.
   - After you set the Custom Function and press the "MODE" button, the camera will be ready to shoot.

Comment: This also applies to the Speedlight 580 EXII - see pages 10 and 27 of the manual.  If you take the batteries out for more than one minute you will need to repeat this procedure.